# Inquiry regarding a linear regression model using Python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression

I have a dataset with nfl historical data from 2003-2023. I wanted to use linear regression to predict the number of wins for the upcoming nfl season.

```
X = nfl.drop('wins', axis=1).values
y = nfl['wins'].values
print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42,         shuffle=True)


model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train

predictions = model.predict(X_test)
```

The predictions variable outputs an array with 128 different values. What should I do to only get 32 values that will correspond to the 32 nfl teams?

Comment: You need to construct a dataframe with 32 rows, with the same columns that are inside the `nfl` dataframe.

Comment: Please share a bit of your dataset, if the teams are 32 then is not built with the team as unique value, so we need to see the structure in order to check what you need

Comment: Can you give the outputs of: X.shape and y.shape?

Comment: The output for X.shape was (672,33) while the output for y.shape was (672,)

Comment: For me, it doesn't look like a regression problem, but more like a multiclass classification problem

Comment: But I agree with Federicokt, it would be necessary to get a glimpse at the first rows of your data. Can you insert them?

Comment: Your predictions here are on your split test data. You have 672 rows so splitting 80/20, leaves that 20% which is your 128 rows. This test set should be used to see how your model performs (is it under fitting, over fitting, etc.). If the model shows to be doing a good job at generalizing the data set, you then want to feed in the new (32 rows for the upcoming season) to do the predictions on. Shoot me an email, I'll help you out. jason.schvach@gmail.com